# Expo java.io.ioexception unexpected end of stream on http

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use Expo Go to scan the QR code after running `npx expo start` on the react native project and the screen shows the error java.io.ioexception unexpected end of the stream. May I ask where will be the problem in order to solve the issue?

[image: Error running react native app]

Comment: tell me about more or give me error screenshot

Comment: I tried one desktop work while another occurred the above problem

Comment: try with npm start and tell me what happened,

Comment: It's the same error that I cannot open the app

Comment: clear go expo cache and check pc and device time both need to same

Comment: Can you show how is the solution?

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: Version 18.17.0

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me after clearing the bundler cache `npx expo start --clear --tunnel`

or

Update the node version to v18.18.0

Comment: It comes out ```CommandError: ngrok tunnel took too long to connect.```

Comment: use node v v18.18.0 or v18.16.0

Comment: How to update my node version?

Comment: check this for reference https://blog.hubspot.com/website/update-node-js

Comment: I got an error when trying to update by ```npm install -g n```

Comment: Can anyone give some guidelines to solve the above issue?

Comment: Have you update node version?

Comment: Yes I am using v18.18.0

Comment: Try to Run in real device

Comment: Same issue as emulator

Comment: give me your steps

Answer (score 1):

To me worked clear the Expo cache data on android. Holding pressed the Expo Go -> App info -> storage -> Clear data